# Is it better to use `require(success)` or to manually revert the state with `if (!success) {...}`?

Tags: solidity

What are the main differences between these two approaches? What is the best practice?

```
balance -= amount;
(bool success,) = adr.call{value: amount}("");
require(success);
```

```
balance -= amount;
(bool success,) = adr.call{value: amount}("");
if (!success) balance += amount;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Solidity, it is generally recommended to use the `require()` function to validate inputs and conditions that must be met in order for a function to execute successfully.

When a `require()` statement evaluates to false, it will automatically revert the state changes made so far in the current transaction, and any gas used up to that point will be refunded.

Using an if statement to check for success and manually reverting the state using the `revert()` function can also achieve the same result, but it requires more manual coding and can be prone to errors, which you made here as well.

Note that you haven't called `revert()`! So in case of an attack e.g. a call to a contract that doesn't act as expected, the success would be false, but you will only change back the balance to the given amount. What will happen to the rest of the actions taken by the unknown contract? This is why you must use `revert()` in case of an unknown failure.

From this part, I will explain some minor differences between `require()` and `if (...) {revert()}`

Using require() helps to make the code more **readable** and **easier to understand**.

Note that it is currently not possible to use **custom errors** in combination with `require()`. You should use `if (!condition) revert CustomError();` instead.

In terms of **gas usage**, I have compiled two contracts with the exact same code except for the differences you have in your question. Here are the gas estimates for the creation of each contract:

Contract with the `require()` statement:
"Creation": {
"codeDepositCost": "116600",
"executionCost": "22271",
"totalCost": "138871"
}

Contract with the if statement:
"Creation": {
"codeDepositCost": "131000",
"executionCost": "22283",
"totalCost": "153283"
}

This difference is due to the `balance += amount` statement which consumes gas (writing to storage is costly!). If we used `if (...) { revert()}` the creation cost would be exactly the same as the `require()` contract:
"Creation": {
"codeDepositCost": "116600",
"executionCost": "22271",
"totalCost": "138871"
}

In the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions), it is mentioned that "The two ways `if (!condition) revert(...);` and `require(condition, ...);` are equivalent as long as the arguments to revert and require do not have side-effects, for example, if they are just strings."

So, at the end of the day, there isn't much difference and it's mostly based on yourself and the use case.

EDIT: Based on [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123381/when-should-i-use-require-vs-custom-revert-errors#:%7E:text=Custom%20errors%20are%20more%20gas,always%20use%20this%20over%20require), it is preferred to use custom errors instead of `require` with a string for better gas efficiency. For more info on custom errors check [this blog](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/).

Comment: From my pov, if + revert with custom error > require

Comment: @JosepBové Why is that?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123381/when-should-i-use-require-vs-custom-revert-errors#:~:text=Custom%20errors%20are%20more%20gas,always%20use%20this%20over%20require.

Comment: Nice. I will edit my response then.